# in Python, I can't seem to find the same items in a list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, sorting

> tuple= [['nike airjordan kahverengi', 42, 6],['nike airjordan sarı', 42, 10], ['nike airjordan mavi', 42, 8],['nike airjordan yeşil', 42, 9]['nike airjordan sarı', 42, 10]]

```
def getOrderList(self):
        orderSplit = ''.join(self.orderText).splitlines()
        productList = []
        for idx, i in enumerate(orderSplit, start = 0):
            if(idx > self.starting_point):
                if i == '@':
                    break
                else:    
                    productList.append([i.rstrip(i[-3:]), int(i[-2:]),idx])
            

        return productList
```

this is the function which gets tuple

```
orderList = self.product.getOrderList()
```

here I am looking for the same ones in the tuple from now on

Comment: Please show the code you've tried, and explain how items are to be considered the same. The sub-lists in your example have different values at index 2.

Comment: Following on from @BilltheLizard see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how you should format your question and what information to include to help us give you an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map your lists to tuples and use `collections.Counter`:

```
lsts = [['nike airjordan kahverengi', 42, 6],['nike airjordan sarı', 42, 10],
        ['nike airjordan mavi', 42, 8],['nike airjordan yeşil', 42, 9],
        ['nike airjordan sarı', 42, 10]]

from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(map(tuple, lsts))

for k,v in counts.items():
    print(list(k), 'appears', v, 'time(s).')
```

Output:

```
['nike airjordan kahverengi', 42, 6] appears 1 time(s).
['nike airjordan sarı', 42, 10] appears 2 time(s).
['nike airjordan mavi', 42, 8] appears 1 time(s).
['nike airjordan yeşil', 42, 9] appears 1 time(s).
```

​